# What conferences have technical sessions that cover credible and transformative alternatives to chemical-rocket-based launch?

Tags: launch, design-alternative, interplanetary, future-missions, cost-to-orbit

**Constraints**

Some examples of such technologies are described on [Wikipedia's Non-Rocket Spacelaunch page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-rocket_spacelaunch). But, to clarify a bit further...

I found list of such technologies in Figure 2.1 of a document entitled [NASA Space Technology Roadmaps and Priorities Revisited (2016)](http://nap.nationalacademies.org/23582). Some highlights (ordered here from lowest to highest scoring):

- 1.5.5. Nuclear (Launch Engines)
- 1.5.3. Space Tether Assist (for launch)
- 1.5.4. Beamed Energy / Energy Addition
- 1.3.5. Ramjet/Scramjet Engines (Accelerators)
- 1.2.4. Detonation Wave Engines (Closed Cycle)
- 1.3.3. Detonation Wave Engines (Open Cycle)
- 1.5.2. Air Launch / Drop Systems
- 1.5.1. Ground Launch Assist
- 1.3.7. Air Collection and Enrichment System
- 1.3.6. Deeply Cooled Air Cycles
- 1.3.8. Fundamental Air Breathing Propulsion Technologies

**Of Interest - Technologies That:**

- Are aiming for at least a factor of 10 reduction in launch costs for a relevant high-volume mission class (such as maintaining a supply chain to a large space station, or setting up a base on The Moon or Mars), and
- Are equal to or better than chemical rockets on safety and environmental impact.

**Not of Interest:**

- Sessions covering various incremental improvements to chemical-rocket-based launch systems.
- Sessions covering ideas that do not pencil out without assuming that, in the future, at least one major breakthrough occurs in, for example, materials science and engineering.

Future conferences are most interesting, but past conferences are of interest too if some information is available about them online.

Details such as...

- typical abstract submission deadline,
- typical conference dates,
- registration cost,
- early bird deadline,
- location,
- and periodicity

... are also of interest.

Comment: Something like the AIAA SciTech Forum (https://www.aiaa.org/scitech) ?

Comment: Can you provide this info as an answer? Then people can comment and vote on it, which will give more information to other people on how relevant this conference is to the question.

Comment: Kinda hurts to see nuclear engines scored so low, but it makes sense.